# Display the original name of the imported module in Coq

Tags: coq

How to choose the textual representation of variables which belongs to some module? (Please see commentaries inside the code below. It's like Notation for modules.) I want to use it because it's preferable to see the original meaning of the terms. (and separate different types with the same realization: SetVars.t, FuncSymb.t, PredSymb.t, etc)

```
Require Import Coq.Structures.Equalities.
Require Import Arith.PeanoNat.
Module mod1 (SetVars : UsualDecidableTypeFull).
Definition h:SetVars.t->SetVars.t := fun x => x. (*example*)
End mod1.

Module mod2.
Module SetVars := PeanoNat.Nat.
Module X := mod1 SetVars.
Import X.
Theorem q:SetVars.t->SetVars.t.
Proof. exact h. Defined. (* Here everything is OK *)
Check h. (*"h : nat -> nat"*)
(*But I want to see "h:SetVars.t->SetVars.t"*)
End mod2.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
Module SetVars := PeanoNat.Nat.
```

with

```
Module SetVars : UsualDecidableTypeFull := PeanoNat.Nat.
```

This makes the module `SetVars` opaque, exposing exactly the signature `UsualDecidableTypeFull`, so that the type `SetVars.t -> SetVars.t` can no longer be reduced.